# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

when I install SQL Server 2008 R2, I get this error. Why?

[image]

http://i52.tinypic.com/2ik4c47.jpg

Comment: Because everything's already installed?

Comment: But, my friend installed only failover cluster installation (only management part). But, i want to install stand alone installation in localhost. How?

Comment: Which options did you select earlier? Did you select to install new features or update existing ones?

Comment: ok, i uninstall this version. because this version is express. so, i install full version. it is work. thanks.